# Deployment onto OpenShift Tomcat 7 is not successful anymore

Tags: java, spring, git, tomcat, openshift

WE deploy our Web Spring/Hibernate  application on the openshift Tomcat 7.0 from our Git repository. We use the free plan.  It used to be OK, but suddenly the successful deployment stopped.  Most of the time the deployment is simply stuck. Finally we got the following error:

```
webResources [/var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/resources/spring] to [/var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/target/rentapp] 
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [/var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/resources] to [/var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/target/rentapp] 
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1119 msecs] [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/app-root/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 51.339s 
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 27 18:39:48 EDT 2016 [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/124M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Preparing build for deployment Deployment id is b822d97e Activating deployment Starting jbossews cartridge jbossews process failed to start 
------------------------- 
Git Post-Receive Result: failure 
Activation status: failure Activation failed for the following gears: 579937937628e1baed000140 
(Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/579937937628e1baed000140/jbossews #<IO:0x000000023b72a0> #<IO:0x000000023b7228> ) 
Deployment completed with status: failure postreceive failed
```

Comment: You should reformat your log

Comment: I can not believe. Something wrong with tool which you are using for viewing results. May be it is simply windows notepad which fails to properly read \r\n. Use notepad++, far, vim or any other *nix viewers.

Comment: That is exactly how we see the error on the deployment screen - the error description is white on the red background.  We do not use shell to see the Log files

Comment: So you should at least format it manually in order do not bother readers

Comment: The output has been reformatted to be more human readable